# Ethernet communication Infineon Aurix TC29x Starter Kit

Tags: embedded, ethernet, infineon

I am trying to enable ethernet communication on an Infineon Aurix Tricore, specifically TC29x. To this end I am using the Aurix SW_framework_tools and the ILLD supplied by Infineon on their Aurix [workspace page (if you ask for access)](https://workspace.infineon.com/cms/en/product/login.html).

In the ILLD package and demo, they have a ethernet demo with loopback_mode enabled. This demo works fine on the board. I then wanted to send out a package to another machine to enable ethernet communication. I have tried fiddling around with settings, using wireshark with cross-over-cable, wireshark with switch, against windows and linux pc's. With no packages received

I am therefore unsure if the demo has the pinmap configured correctly, and/or if some settings I have missed should be changed. My question is therefore if anyone has enabled ethernet communication using the infineon tools, and can guide me?

**Tools**

I have chosen the HighTec toolchain using the debuger UDE, all are from the free tools available on Infineon.

**Board**

Infineon Aurix Tricore TC299 Starter Kit.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If you have solved it , please help me with the solution .

Comment: @JasdeepSinghArora unfortunately not, we are looking at buying an OS from a vendor. If you have any success in your coming work please share.